# Assigning road road segments to single line file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, splitting

I am working on a map of traffic data.

How can I join my excel spreadsheet which has traffic data based on segments of a road to the shapefiles where each road is a single line file?

Do I have to use the split tool?

Comment: I think there must be a word missing between "my" and "which" but please re-read your question to see if you can make what you are asking clear. Perhaps add a picture.

Comment: This is a broad topic, try searching on [HPMS conflation](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=hpms+conflation).

Answer (score 1):

If you have two cross street descriptions in a table row and a unique Row ID that can be copied to other tables you can use Geocoding and Linear Referencing.  First you have to geocode the intersection locations as points for the from intersection and the to intersection descriptions along with their common Row ID into separate point files.

Then make your road network a Linear Referencing Network with the Create Routes tool to create a route for each road.  Next use the Locate Features Along Routes tool you can convert the two point feature classes into LR point event tables containing the Route ID and measure of the point.  As long as the from and to point have a field with an original record field ID these two event tables can be joined on that field and then exported to create an event table with a route and two measures (a from measure and a to measure)  That is all you need to create a line segment that has your original row data.  You then can use the Make Route Event Layer tool to display your event table line segments and they will match the two cross street descriptions of your original file (provided you had decent results during the intersection geocoding step).

See also this question on Geonet about ["How to geocode lines"](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/177913)